# Rcpp Windows Failed Compilation

Tags: c++, windows, compilation, rcpp

I developed Rcpp code and it compiles on Linux, but I'm attempting windows.

I installed Rtools, and the paths are set, the paths appear to be correct.

```
> Sys.getenv("PATH")
[1] "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.3.0\\bin\\x64;c:\\Rtools\\bin;c:\\Rtools\\gcc-4.6.3\\bin;c:\\MiKTeX\\miktex\\bin;c:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.3.0\\bin\\;c:\\windows;c:\\windows\\system32;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\iCLS Client\\;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\iCLS Client\\;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32;C:\\WINDOWS;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32Files (x86)"
```

I have g++ installed

```
> system("g++ -v")
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=c:\Rtools\GCC-46~1.3\bin\G__~1.EXE
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/rtools/gcc-46~1.3/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: i686-w64-mingw32
Configured with: /data/gannet/ripley/Sources/mingw-test3/src/gcc/configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=i686-w64-mingw32 --with-sysroot=/data/gannet/ripley/Sources/mingw-test3/mingw32mingw32/mingw32 --prefix=/data/gannet/ripley/Sources/mingw-test3/mingw32mingw32/mingw32 --with-    gmp=/data/gannet/ripley/Sources/mingw-test3/mingw32mingw32/prereq_install --with-mpfr=/data/gannet/ripley/Sources/mingw
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.6.3 20111208 (prerelease) (GCC)
```

Make is also installed by Rtools

```
> system("where make")
c:\Rtools\bin\make.exe



 system("R CMD INSTALL ./Sage_1.03.tar.gz")
* installing to library 'C:/Users/Melannies/Documents/R/win-library/3.3'
* installing *source* package 'Sage' ...
** libs
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG        -I"C:/Users/Melannies/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/Rcpp/include" -I"C:/Users/Melannies/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/RcppArmadillo/include" -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"  `-IC:/Users/Melannies/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/Rcpp/include   -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 2
Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars.win" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.0/etc/x64/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.0/share/make/winshlib.mk"  SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="speedSage.dll" WIN=64 TCLBIN=64 OBJECTS="RcppExports.o aggregategsSumSigma.o bayesEstimation.o calcVIFarm_nosdalphaalt.o calcVIFarmalt.o notbayesEstimation.o sigmaArm.o sigmaSingle.o"' had status 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'Sage'
* removing 'C:/Users/Melannies/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/speedSage'
  Warning message:
running command 'R CMD INSTALL ./speedSage_1.03.tar.gz' had status 1
```

So I don't know the error RcppExports?   I've tried to subscribe to Rcpp-Devel but have had trouble.

here is the Makevars.win

```
# Use the R_HOME indirection to support installations of multiple R version
PKG_LIBS = $(shell "${R_HOME}/bin${R_ARCH_BIN}/Rscript.exe" -e "Rcpp:::LdFlags()")
PKG_CXXFLAGS=`$(shell "${R_HOME}/bin${R_ARCH_BIN}/Rscript.exe" -e "Rcpp:::CxxFlags()")
```

I do have LinkingTo: in the DESCRIPTION ,  but am not sure how to fully use LinkingTo

```
Package: Sage
Type: Package
Title: accelerated Client package 
Version: 1.04

Depends:
     Rcpp (>= 0.10.3),
     RcppArmadillo (>= 0.3.810.2),
     R (>= 2.15.0),
     stats,
     utils,
     arkas
Suggests: knitr,
      roxygen2
VignetteBuilder: knitr
Maintainer: anthony colombo <anthonycolombo60@gmail.com>
Description: Computes the necessary statistics for analysis using R 
License: GPL (>= 2)
LinkingTo: Rcpp, RcppArmadillo
RoxygenNote: 5.0.1
NeedsCompilation: yes
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is given by:

> Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution

Since a

```
`
```

is in the start of the last line in the `Makevars.win`:

```
PKG_CXXFLAGS=`$(shell "${R_HOME}/bin${R_ARCH_BIN}/Rscript.exe" -e "Rcpp:::CxxFlags()")
```

Switch it to:

```
PKG_CXXFLAGS=$(shell "${R_HOME}/bin${R_ARCH_BIN}/Rscript.exe" -e "Rcpp:::CxxFlags()")
```

And you should be golden.

By the way... [You should switch over the `LinkingTo:` feature of `Rcpp`.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-package.pdf#page=3) As this is very old-school (*vintage Rcpp?*) way of linking.

Comment: wow thank you. I will try this again tonight, this could very well be the solution.

Comment: Try it now with `devtools::build_win()`!

Comment: I copied my Linux package to Dropbox, then downloaded the package to the windows system, and it failed.  is it required to build the package on a Windows system, for it to install on a windows OS?  thank you.

Comment: Yes. Binaries are platform dependent. Source code is not.

Comment: the build_win() is very helpful.  the issue that fails the build is the way I switch coordinates from an R vector (1 based) into a Rcpp vector (0 based).   Here is a line when I swtich coordinates into Rcpp Vector, Rcpp::NumericVector dof = DOF[index-1]; the error returns as warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second.  Having a bit of trouble here.  thank you for any pointers.

Comment: Create unit tests with testthat on each function you create.

Comment: thank you for your answers, if I have more technical problems I will go to Rcpp-devel list.   testthat, and build_win great suggestions.  tyvm.

Comment: I'm getting ambigious implicit assignments from using Sugar and Rcpp that windows is not compiling... technical issues....